# Display Html tags for each Return in LOV

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, apex

I want to have an lov for showing something like Likert scale in **Interactive Report**.
and it's base on one of my columns.
here's my code :

```
APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY(P_IDX   => 1,
                                 P_VALUE =>a.answer_number, ---My column Name 
                                 P_QUERY => ' SELECT
    CASE level
      WHEN 1 THEN ''<img  class="origin_image" src="#WORKSPACE_FILES#1.PNG" width="10px" height="10px" >''          
      WHEN 2 THEN ''<img  class="origin_image" src="#WORKSPACE_FILES#2.PNG" width="10px" height="10px">''
      WHEN 3 THEN ''<img  class="origin_image" src="#WORKSPACE_FILES#3.PNG" width="10px" height="10px">'' 
      WHEN 4 THEN ''<img  class="origin_image" src="#WORKSPACE_FILES#4.PNG" width="10px" height="10px">''
      WHEN 5 THEN ''<img  class="origin_image" src="#WORKSPACE_FILES#5.PNG" width="10px" height="10px">'' 
    END as d,
   level
     as r
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY level <= 5;')
```

as you all see , the image that I want should be displayed in my IR but it recognizes as a text not image .
any suggestion for showing LOV base on custom pictures ?
Besides if you know any component for this feature please recommend them !

Comment: As far as I can tell, Apex doesn't support that. Perhaps you should search for a plug-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way that I can use **unicodes of emojies** based on my **NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET** !
and then I re-write my LOV like this :

```
    SELECT
    CASE level
    WHEN 1 THEN  unistr('\D83D\DE0E')          
    WHEN 2 THEN unistr('\D83D\DE0A')
    WHEN 3 THEN unistr('\D83D\DE03')
    WHEN 4 THEN unistr('\D83D\DE10')     
    END as d,
    level  as r       
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY level <= 4;
```

and here is the result : [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3GYu.png)

Note : if you want to know what is your **NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET** use this select :

```
SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS;
```

then You have the search Unicodes of emojies , this website could be helpful :
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/search?q=face#characters